# closest() for getting a html value from the previous td

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

http://jsfiddle.net/twkRY/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="iwant">ttt</td>
        <td>some text <span class="txt">haha</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(".txt").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).closest("td.iwant").html())
})
```

It just gives undefined. Why not *ttt*?

**edit**: i know the solution how to make it work with `prev` and `parent`, I just want to know why `closest` doesn't work.

Comment: `jQuery.closest()` traverses *up*, you want `jQuery.prev()` or `jQuery.prevAll('.iwant')`.

Comment: `jQuery.closest()` is more akin to `jQuery.parents()`.

Comment: `closest` doesn't work as `td.iwant` is not a parent of `.txt` element

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): _get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._ `td.iwant` is not an ancestor of `.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the `closest` `td` and then get the previous sibling with `prev`.

```
$(this).closest("td").prev(".iwant").html()
```

Comment: `prevAll` might be used in general case or `prev` without selector

Comment: @evening - The reason this would work is that the `td` you want to get is (apparently in all cases) not an ancestor of `.txt`, so `.closest()` cannot traverse up linearly to find it. You're looking for a sibling of the ancestor. Depending on use case, I would probably use `.prevAll()` to move laterally instead of `.prev()`, unless `.prev()` does something I'm unaware of?

Comment: @JaredFarrish That is true, though often not intended.  Depends on the real situation.